# Openshift - rhc tail command

Tags: logging, openshift, tail, openshift-client-tools

When I try directly run **rhc tail** from app dir it allways tell:

> C:\Documents and Settings\user\git\service>rhc tail You must specify
>   an application with -a, or run this command from within Git directory
>   cloned from OpenShift. Usage: rhc tail  Pass '--help' to
>   see the full list of options

I cloned the application right before it. 
What is the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you used `git clone <repository_url>` then you have to use `rhc tail --app <app_name>` command. If you want rhc tail to figure out app name for you, then you should use `rhc git-clone --app <app_name>` command to clone the repository. The `rhc git-clone` command adds few properties to your `.git/config` file that OpenShift uses to determine app name, that looks like this:

```
[rhc]
    app-id = 64546576654634028d
    app-name = example
    domain-name = example
```

Comment: Actualy we do not net clone application from <repository_url> if we create app from rhc, yea? It clones automaticaly.

Answer (score 0):

Update file .git/config to include this section:

```
[rhc]
    app-id = <your_app_id>
    app-name = <your_app_name>
    domain-name = <your_app_domain>
```

Actually, these values should be present in this file just a few lines above in the section [remote "origin"]. Checkout this line:

```
url = ssh://<your_app_id>@<your_app_name>-<your_app_domain>.rhcloud.com/~/git/portfolio.git/
```

You can use values stated in this variable to update information for rhc client.